# Correctly displaying data in optgroups

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have an issue with MySQL displaying results correctly when I add the php code to the snippet below.

When it runs it displays everything correctly except when I click on the `<optgroup>` it only reads the first `<option></option>` rather than reading everything in the `<optgroup></optgroup>` When I try to use GROUP BY in the MYSQL everything is fixed except it only displays a single column from my database rather than everything filtered.

I am pretty sure the error is somewhere in my PHP code as I think the code is writing an optgroup for every option so it is reading it something like this

```
<optgroup>
<option>option 1</option>
</optgroup>

<optgroup>
<option>option 2</option>
</optgroup>

<optgroup>
<option>option 3</option>
</optgroup>
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users`,`departments` WHERE users.dept = departments.dept_name";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
   echo "<select name='test[]' id='optgroup' class='ms' multiple='multiple'>";?>
   <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
     echo "<optgroup label=".$row['dept_name'].">
       <option value=".$row['user_name'].">".$row['user_name']."</option>
     </optgroup>";}?>
</select>
```

`Users` table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` 
(
     `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `user_role` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     `user_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     `gender` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     `dob` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     `phone` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
     `dept` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     `userpic` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

`DEPARTMENTS` table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `departments` 
(
     `dept_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `dept_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     `dept_supervisor` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     `dept_desc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     `dept_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     `dept_phone` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`dept_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

SNIPPET:

```
/*
* MultiSelect v0.9.12
* Copyright (c) 2012 Louis Cuny
*
* This program is free software. It comes without any warranty, to
* the extent permitted by applicable law. You can redistribute it
* and/or modify it under the terms of the Do What The Fuck You Want
* To Public License, Version 2, as published by Sam Hocevar. See
* http://sam.zoy.org/wtfpl/COPYING for more details.
*/

!function ($) {

  "use strict";


 /* MULTISELECT CLASS DEFINITION
  * ====================== */

  var MultiSelect = function (element, options) {
    this.options = options;
    this.$element = $(element);
    this.$container = $('<div/>', { 'class': "ms-container" });
    this.$selectableContainer = $('<div/>', { 'class': 'ms-selectable' });
    this.$selectionContainer = $('<div/>', { 'class': 'ms-selection' });
    this.$selectableUl = $('<ul/>', { 'class': "ms-list", 'tabindex' : '-1' });
    this.$selectionUl = $('<ul/>', { 'class': "ms-list", 'tabindex' : '-1' });
    this.scrollTo = 0;
    this.elemsSelector = 'li:visible:not(.ms-optgroup-label,.ms-optgroup-container,.'+options.disabledClass+')';
  };

  MultiSelect.prototype = {
    constructor: MultiSelect,

    init: function(){
      var that = this,
          ms = this.$element;

      if (ms.next('.ms-container').length === 0){
        ms.css({ position: 'absolute', left: '-9999px' });
        ms.attr('id', ms.attr('id') ? ms.attr('id') : Math.ceil(Math.random()*1000)+'multiselect');
        this.$container.attr('id', 'ms-'+ms.attr('id'));
        this.$container.addClass(that.options.cssClass);
        ms.find('option').each(function(){
          that.generateLisFromOption(this);
        });

        this.$selectionUl.find('.ms-optgroup-label').hide();

        if (that.options.selectableHeader){
          that.$selectableContainer.append(that.options.selectableHeader);
        }
        that.$selectableContainer.append(that.$selectableUl);
        if (that.options.selectableFooter){
          that.$selectableContainer.append(that.options.selectableFooter);
        }

        if (that.options.selectionHeader){
          that.$selectionContainer.append(that.options.selectionHeader);
        }
        that.$selectionContainer.append(that.$selectionUl);
        if (that.options.selectionFooter){
          that.$selectionContainer.append(that.options.selectionFooter);
        }

        that.$container.append(that.$selectableContainer);
        that.$container.append(that.$selectionContainer);
        ms.after(that.$container);

        that.activeMouse(that.$selectableUl);
        that.activeKeyboard(that.$selectableUl);

        var action = that.options.dblClick ? 'dblclick' : 'click';

        that.$selectableUl.on(action, '.ms-elem-selectable', function(){
          that.select($(this).data('ms-value'));
        });
        that.$selectionUl.on(action, '.ms-elem-selection', function(){
          that.deselect($(this).data('ms-value'));
        });

        that.activeMouse(that.$selectionUl);
        that.activeKeyboard(that.$selectionUl);

        ms.on('focus', function(){
          that.$selectableUl.focus();
        });
      }

      var selectedValues = ms.find('option:selected').map(function(){ return $(this).val(); }).get();
      that.select(selectedValues, 'init');

      if (typeof that.options.afterInit === 'function') {
        that.options.afterInit.call(this, this.$container);
      }
    },

    'generateLisFromOption' : function(option, index, $container){
      var that = this,
          ms = that.$element,
          attributes = "",
          $option = $(option);

      for (var cpt = 0; cpt < option.attributes.length; cpt++){
        var attr = option.attributes[cpt];

        if(attr.name !== 'value' && attr.name !== 'disabled'){
          attributes += attr.name+'="'+attr.value+'" ';
        }
      }
      var selectableLi = $('<li '+attributes+'><span>'+that.escapeHTML($option.text())+'</span></li>'),
          selectedLi = selectableLi.clone(),
          value = $option.val(),
          elementId = that.sanitize(value);

      selectableLi
        .data('ms-value', value)
        .addClass('ms-elem-selectable')
        .attr('id', elementId+'-selectable');

      selectedLi
        .data('ms-value', value)
        .addClass('ms-elem-selection')
        .attr('id', elementId+'-selection')
        .hide();

      if ($option.prop('disabled') || ms.prop('disabled')){
        selectedLi.addClass(that.options.disabledClass);
        selectableLi.addClass(that.options.disabledClass);
      }

      var $optgroup = $option.parent('optgroup');

      if ($optgroup.length > 0){
        var optgroupLabel = $optgroup.attr('label'),
            optgroupId = that.sanitize(optgroupLabel),
            $selectableOptgroup = that.$selectableUl.find('#optgroup-selectable-'+optgroupId),
            $selectionOptgroup = that.$selectionUl.find('#optgroup-selection-'+optgroupId);

        if ($selectableOptgroup.length === 0){
          var optgroupContainerTpl = '<li class="ms-optgroup-container"></li>',
              optgroupTpl = '<ul class="ms-optgroup"><li class="ms-optgroup-label"><span>'+optgroupLabel+'</span></li></ul>';

          $selectableOptgroup = $(optgroupContainerTpl);
          $selectionOptgroup = $(optgroupContainerTpl);
          $selectableOptgroup.attr('id', 'optgroup-selectable-'+optgroupId);
          $selectionOptgroup.attr('id', 'optgroup-selection-'+optgroupId);
          $selectableOptgroup.append($(optgroupTpl));
          $selectionOptgroup.append($(optgroupTpl));
          if (that.options.selectableOptgroup){
            $selectableOptgroup.find('.ms-optgroup-label').on('click', function(){
              var values = $optgroup.children(':not(:selected, :disabled)').map(function(){ return $(this).val();}).get();
              that.select(values);
            });
            $selectionOptgroup.find('.ms-optgroup-label').on('click', function(){
              var values = $optgroup.children(':selected:not(:disabled)').map(function(){ return $(this).val();}).get();
              that.deselect(values);
            });
          }
          that.$selectableUl.append($selectableOptgroup);
          that.$selectionUl.append($selectionOptgroup);
        }
        index = index === undefined ? $selectableOptgroup.find('ul').children().length : index + 1;
        selectableLi.insertAt(index, $selectableOptgroup.children());
        selectedLi.insertAt(index, $selectionOptgroup.children());
      } else {
        index = index === undefined ? that.$selectableUl.children().length : index;

        selectableLi.insertAt(index, that.$selectableUl);
        selectedLi.insertAt(index, that.$selectionUl);
      }
    },

    'addOption' : function(options){
      var that = this;

      if (options.value !== undefined && options.value !== null){
        options = [options];
      } 
      $.each(options, function(index, option){
        if (option.value !== undefined && option.value !== null &&
            that.$element.find("option[value='"+option.value+"']").length === 0){
          var $option = $('<option value="'+option.value+'">'+option.text+'</option>'),
              index = parseInt((typeof option.index === 'undefined' ? that.$element.children().length : option.index)),
              $container = option.nested === undefined ? that.$element : $("optgroup[label='"+option.nested+"']");

          $option.insertAt(index, $container);
          that.generateLisFromOption($option.get(0), index, option.nested);
        }
      });
    },

    'escapeHTML' : function(text){
      return $("<div>").text(text).html();
    },

    'activeKeyboard' : function($list){
      var that = this;

      $list.on('focus', function(){
        $(this).addClass('ms-focus');
      })
      .on('blur', function(){
        $(this).removeClass('ms-focus');
      })
      .on('keydown', function(e){
        switch (e.which) {
          case 40:
          case 38:
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            that.moveHighlight($(this), (e.which === 38) ? -1 : 1);
            return;
          case 37:
          case 39:
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            that.switchList($list);
            return;
          case 9:
            if(that.$element.is('[tabindex]')){
              e.preventDefault();
              var tabindex = parseInt(that.$element.attr('tabindex'), 10);
              tabindex = (e.shiftKey) ? tabindex-1 : tabindex+1;
              $('[tabindex="'+(tabindex)+'"]').focus();
              return;
            }else{
              if(e.shiftKey){
                that.$element.trigger('focus');
              }
            }
        }
        if($.inArray(e.which, that.options.keySelect) > -1){
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
          that.selectHighlighted($list);
          return;
        }
      });
    },

    'moveHighlight': function($list, direction){
      var $elems = $list.find(this.elemsSelector),
          $currElem = $elems.filter('.ms-hover'),
          $nextElem = null,
          elemHeight = $elems.first().outerHeight(),
          containerHeight = $list.height(),
          containerSelector = '#'+this.$container.prop('id');

      $elems.removeClass('ms-hover');
      if (direction === 1){ // DOWN

        $nextElem = $currElem.nextAll(this.elemsSelector).first();
        if ($nextElem.length === 0){
          var $optgroupUl = $currElem.parent();

          if ($optgroupUl.hasClass('ms-optgroup')){
            var $optgroupLi = $optgroupUl.parent(),
                $nextOptgroupLi = $optgroupLi.next(':visible');

            if ($nextOptgroupLi.length > 0){
              $nextElem = $nextOptgroupLi.find(this.elemsSelector).first();
            } else {
              $nextElem = $elems.first();
            }
          } else {
            $nextElem = $elems.first();
          }
        }
      } else if (direction === -1){ // UP

        $nextElem = $currElem.prevAll(this.elemsSelector).first();
        if ($nextElem.length === 0){
          var $optgroupUl = $currElem.parent();

          if ($optgroupUl.hasClass('ms-optgroup')){
            var $optgroupLi = $optgroupUl.parent(),
                $prevOptgroupLi = $optgroupLi.prev(':visible');

            if ($prevOptgroupLi.length > 0){
              $nextElem = $prevOptgroupLi.find(this.elemsSelector).last();
            } else {
              $nextElem = $elems.last();
            }
          } else {
            $nextElem = $elems.last();
          }
        }
      }
      if ($nextElem.length > 0){
        $nextElem.addClass('ms-hover');
        var scrollTo = $list.scrollTop() + $nextElem.position().top - 
                       containerHeight / 2 + elemHeight / 2;

        $list.scrollTop(scrollTo);
      }
    },

    'selectHighlighted' : function($list){
      var $elems = $list.find(this.elemsSelector),
          $highlightedElem = $elems.filter('.ms-hover').first();

      if ($highlightedElem.length > 0){
        if ($list.parent().hasClass('ms-selectable')){
          this.select($highlightedElem.data('ms-value'));
        } else {
          this.deselect($highlightedElem.data('ms-value'));
        }
        $elems.removeClass('ms-hover');
      }
    },

    'switchList' : function($list){
      $list.blur();
      this.$container.find(this.elemsSelector).removeClass('ms-hover');
      if ($list.parent().hasClass('ms-selectable')){
        this.$selectionUl.focus();
      } else {
        this.$selectableUl.focus();
      }
    },

    'activeMouse' : function($list){
      var that = this;

      this.$container.on('mouseenter', that.elemsSelector, function(){
        $(this).parents('.ms-container').find(that.elemsSelector).removeClass('ms-hover');
        $(this).addClass('ms-hover');
      });

      this.$container.on('mouseleave', that.elemsSelector, function () {
        $(this).parents('.ms-container').find(that.elemsSelector).removeClass('ms-hover');
      });
    },

    'refresh' : function() {
      this.destroy();
      this.$element.multiSelect(this.options);
    },

    'destroy' : function(){
      $("#ms-"+this.$element.attr("id")).remove();
      this.$element.off('focus');
      this.$element.css('position', '').css('left', '');
      this.$element.removeData('multiselect');
    },

    'select' : function(value, method){
      if (typeof value === 'string'){ value = [value]; }

      var that = this,
          ms = this.$element,
          msIds = $.map(value, function(val){ return(that.sanitize(val)); }),
          selectables = this.$selectableUl.find('#' + msIds.join('-selectable, #')+'-selectable').filter(':not(.'+that.options.disabledClass+')'),
          selections = this.$selectionUl.find('#' + msIds.join('-selection, #') + '-selection').filter(':not(.'+that.options.disabledClass+')'),
          options = ms.find('option:not(:disabled)').filter(function(){ return($.inArray(this.value, value) > -1); });

      if (method === 'init'){
        selectables = this.$selectableUl.find('#' + msIds.join('-selectable, #')+'-selectable'),
        selections = this.$selectionUl.find('#' + msIds.join('-selection, #') + '-selection');
      }

      if (selectables.length > 0){
        selectables.addClass('ms-selected').hide();
        selections.addClass('ms-selected').show();

        options.prop('selected', true);

        that.$container.find(that.elemsSelector).removeClass('ms-hover');

        var selectableOptgroups = that.$selectableUl.children('.ms-optgroup-container');
        if (selectableOptgroups.length > 0){
          selectableOptgroups.each(function(){
            var selectablesLi = $(this).find('.ms-elem-selectable');
            if (selectablesLi.length === selectablesLi.filter('.ms-selected').length){
              $(this).find('.ms-optgroup-label').hide();
            }
          });

          var selectionOptgroups = that.$selectionUl.children('.ms-optgroup-container');
          selectionOptgroups.each(function(){
            var selectionsLi = $(this).find('.ms-elem-selection');
            if (selectionsLi.filter('.ms-selected').length > 0){
              $(this).find('.ms-optgroup-label').show();
            }
          });
        } else {
          if (that.options.keepOrder && method !== 'init'){
            var selectionLiLast = that.$selectionUl.find('.ms-selected');
            if((selectionLiLast.length > 1) && (selectionLiLast.last().get(0) != selections.get(0))) {
              selections.insertAfter(selectionLiLast.last());
            }
          }
        }
        if (method !== 'init'){
          ms.trigger('change');
          if (typeof that.options.afterSelect === 'function') {
            that.options.afterSelect.call(this, value);
          }
        }
      }
    },

    'deselect' : function(value){
      if (typeof value === 'string'){ value = [value]; }

      var that = this,
          ms = this.$element,
          msIds = $.map(value, function(val){ return(that.sanitize(val)); }),
          selectables = this.$selectableUl.find('#' + msIds.join('-selectable, #')+'-selectable'),
          selections = this.$selectionUl.find('#' + msIds.join('-selection, #')+'-selection').filter('.ms-selected').filter(':not(.'+that.options.disabledClass+')'),
          options = ms.find('option').filter(function(){ return($.inArray(this.value, value) > -1); });

      if (selections.length > 0){
        selectables.removeClass('ms-selected').show();
        selections.removeClass('ms-selected').hide();
        options.prop('selected', false);

        that.$container.find(that.elemsSelector).removeClass('ms-hover');

        var selectableOptgroups = that.$selectableUl.children('.ms-optgroup-container');
        if (selectableOptgroups.length > 0){
          selectableOptgroups.each(function(){
            var selectablesLi = $(this).find('.ms-elem-selectable');
            if (selectablesLi.filter(':not(.ms-selected)').length > 0){
              $(this).find('.ms-optgroup-label').show();
            }
          });

          var selectionOptgroups = that.$selectionUl.children('.ms-optgroup-container');
          selectionOptgroups.each(function(){
            var selectionsLi = $(this).find('.ms-elem-selection');
            if (selectionsLi.filter('.ms-selected').length === 0){
              $(this).find('.ms-optgroup-label').hide();
            }
          });
        }
        ms.trigger('change');
        if (typeof that.options.afterDeselect === 'function') {
          that.options.afterDeselect.call(this, value);
        }
      }
    },

    'select_all' : function(){
      var ms = this.$element,
          values = ms.val();

      ms.find('option:not(":disabled")').prop('selected', true);
      this.$selectableUl.find('.ms-elem-selectable').filter(':not(.'+this.options.disabledClass+')').addClass('ms-selected').hide();
      this.$selectionUl.find('.ms-optgroup-label').show();
      this.$selectableUl.find('.ms-optgroup-label').hide();
      this.$selectionUl.find('.ms-elem-selection').filter(':not(.'+this.options.disabledClass+')').addClass('ms-selected').show();
      this.$selectionUl.focus();
      ms.trigger('change');
      if (typeof this.options.afterSelect === 'function') {
        var selectedValues = $.grep(ms.val(), function(item){
          return $.inArray(item, values) < 0;
        });
        this.options.afterSelect.call(this, selectedValues);
      }
    },

    'deselect_all' : function(){
      var ms = this.$element,
          values = ms.val();

      ms.find('option').prop('selected', false);
      this.$selectableUl.find('.ms-elem-selectable').removeClass('ms-selected').show();
      this.$selectionUl.find('.ms-optgroup-label').hide();
      this.$selectableUl.find('.ms-optgroup-label').show();
      this.$selectionUl.find('.ms-elem-selection').removeClass('ms-selected').hide();
      this.$selectableUl.focus();
      ms.trigger('change');
      if (typeof this.options.afterDeselect === 'function') {
        this.options.afterDeselect.call(this, values);
      }
    },

    sanitize: function(value){
      var hash = 0, i, character;
      if (value.length == 0) return hash;
      var ls = 0;
      for (i = 0, ls = value.length; i < ls; i++) {
        character  = value.charCodeAt(i);
        hash  = ((hash<<5)-hash)+character;
        hash |= 0; // Convert to 32bit integer
      }
      return hash;
    }
  };

  /* MULTISELECT PLUGIN DEFINITION
   * ======================= */

  $.fn.multiSelect = function () {
    var option = arguments[0],
        args = arguments;

    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this),
          data = $this.data('multiselect'),
          options = $.extend({}, $.fn.multiSelect.defaults, $this.data(), typeof option === 'object' && option);

      if (!data){ $this.data('multiselect', (data = new MultiSelect(this, options))); }

      if (typeof option === 'string'){
        data[option](args[1]);
      } else {
        data.init();
      }
    });
  };

  $.fn.multiSelect.defaults = {
    keySelect: [32],
    selectableOptgroup: false,
    disabledClass : 'disabled',
    dblClick : false,
    keepOrder: false,
    cssClass: ''
  };

  $.fn.multiSelect.Constructor = MultiSelect;

  $.fn.insertAt = function(index, $parent) {
    return this.each(function() {
      if (index === 0) {
        $parent.prepend(this);
      } else {
        $parent.children().eq(index - 1).after(this);
      }
    });
};

}(window.jQuery);


//Multi-select
    $('#optgroup').multiSelect({ selectableOptgroup: true });
```

```css
.ms-container{
  background: transparent url('../img/switch.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
  width: 370px;
}

.ms-container:after{
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  clear: both;
  min-height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.ms-container .ms-selectable, .ms-container .ms-selection{
  background: #fff;
  color: #555555;
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
}
.ms-container .ms-selection{
  float: right;
}

.ms-container .ms-list{
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  -o-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.ms-container .ms-list.ms-focus{
  border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
  outline: 0;
  outline: thin dotted \9;
}

.ms-container ul{
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.ms-container .ms-optgroup-container{
  width: 100%;
}

.ms-container .ms-optgroup-label{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #999;
}

.ms-container .ms-selectable li.ms-elem-selectable,
.ms-container .ms-selection li.ms-elem-selection{
  border-bottom: 1px #eee solid;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.ms-container .ms-selectable li.ms-hover,
.ms-container .ms-selection li.ms-hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #08c;
}

.ms-container .ms-selectable li.disabled,
.ms-container .ms-selection li.disabled{
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #aaa;
  cursor: text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="optgroup" class="ms" multiple="multiple">
 <optgroup label="Department 1">
 <option value="employee_1">Employee 1</option>
 <option value="employee_2">Employee 2</option>
 <option value="employee_3">Employee 3</option>
 </optgroup>
  
  <optgroup label="Department 2">
 <option value="employee_4">Employee 4</option>
 <option value="employee_5">Employee 5</option>
 <option value="employee_6">Employee 6</option>
    </optgroup>
    </select>
```

Comment: Your code as written only ever puts one `<option>` into each `<optgroup>` - the `echo` for the `<optgroup>` is *inside* the `while` loop.

Comment: I should make a double loops? one for the optgroups and one for the options?

Comment: Please add a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` as well of the 2 tables users and departments. You will need to adjust the query and then make changes in the while loop as well

Comment: You could do that as well, but if you can post your db structure I'm sure we can create a query for you to use, so you can avoid using double queries since you would first need to select all departments for each optgroup, then department X query will result in more queries than you need to

Comment: Added both the architectures for the tables I don't know if there is a correct syntax in stack to insert the whole table.

Comment: Please run these SQL queries `SHOW CREATE TABLE users` and  `SHOW CREATE TABLE departments`, then the language for syntax highlighting is lang-sql, you could even export some values so we have something to work with

Comment: Sorry for the delay, added both the queries to the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should first get department names and then for each department, execute a query :

```php
<?php 
echo '<select name="test[]" id="optgroup" class="ms" multiple="multiple">';
$departments = mysql_query( 'SELECT DISTINCT dept_name FROM `departments`' );
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $departments ) ){
    // use some sort of character escapeing to prevent XSS
    echo '<optgroup label="', htmlspecialchars( $row['dept_name'] ), '">';
    $users = mysql_query( sprintf( 'SELECT user_name FROM `users` WHERE users.dept = "%s"', mysql_real_escape_string( $row['dept_name'] ) ) );
    while( $user = mysql_fetch_array( $users ) ){
        echo '<option value="', htmlspecialchars( $user['user_name'] ), '">',
            htmlspecialchars( $user['user_name'] ),
        '</option>';
    }
    echo '</optgroup>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: This code has the same problem as the original code. Each `<optgroup>` will only contain one `<option>`.

Comment: While it it the lazy man's way and the fastest to implement, there are alternatives to reduce the N number of departments loop query to just 1. You select all and order by department, then check if the department doesn't equal open and close a new optgroup. Hell even creating a mutlidimensional array with multilevel loops would be faster then this.

Comment: @Pointy updated the answer. I move the `optgroup` element out of while loop

Comment: If you want to do it this way 1. don't run 3 loops only 2: in the first while you don't generate a departments array, just continue creating the query, but before the query echo out the optgroup

Comment: The code is not displaying anything at all and it is giving me a illegal string offset error now

Comment: @Fares Shawa,   Mujnoi Gyula Tamas has edited my answer (thank you), try it again !

Comment: Still it is not fixed even though I believe there was a mistke in this line
 $users = mysql_query( sprintf('SELECT user_name FROM `users` WHERE users.dept = "%s"', mysql_real_escape_string( $row['dept_name']  ));

Comment: My mistake, I sent another edit, missing parentesis and 2 variable typos

Comment: Perfectly works now, Thank you all for your input and solutions!

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki Don't mention it ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the alternative method, which only takes 1 query. Take a look at how I ordered the query it's basicaly the same idea as with the other answear except you're not making N query * the number of departments

```php
<?php
echo '<select name="test[]" id="optgroup" class="ms" multiple="multiple">', "\n";
$select = mysql_query( '
    SELECT
        *
    FROM `users`, `departments`
    WHERE `users`.`dept` = `departments`.`dept_name`
    ORDER BY `departments`.`dept_name`, `users`.`user_name` ASC
' );
$department = false;
if( mysql_num_rows( $select ) ){
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $select ) ){
        if( ! $department || ( $department && $department != $row['dept_name'] ) ){
            // use some sort of character escapeing to prevent XSS
            if( $department ){
                echo '</optgroup>', "\n";
            }
            echo '<optgroup label="', htmlspecialchars( $row['dept_name'] ), '">', "\n";
            $department = $row['dept_name'];
        }
        echo '<option value="', htmlspecialchars( $row['user_name'] ), '">',
            htmlspecialchars( $row['user_name'] ),
        '</option>', "\n";
    }
    echo '</optgroup>', "\n";
}
echo '</select>', "\n";
```