# how to Group header meniu category and subcategory mysqli using stmt statement results and display by parent

Tags: php, loops, mysqli, while-loop

How I can group category and subcategory and display all the results from misqli DB for header meniu? I made a table called `category` with 3 column `id, category, parent` then I grouped the category using `parent` for the with value `parent=0` for the category and the subcatogory value wich corespuning parent with the main category. But the problem is the code show me only the first main category and the first coresponding subcategory, and i want to display all.

so I have 3 category value (`fruits id=1 , parent=0`, `cars id=2 parent=0`, `clothes id=3 parent=0` with `parent=0` that means their are a category header) and e.g. for cars i have 2 subcategory value (`moto id=52 parent=2` `auto id=34 parent=2` ) you got the idea...

```
$parentTake = '0';
$categorieDrowdown = "";
$categorieDrowdownLista = "";
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, category, parent FROM category WHERE parent=?');
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $parentTake);
    $stmt->execute();
    $existCount = $stmt->store_result();
        if($existCount == 0){
    echo "nU ai nici o categorie adaugata";
     exit();
        }
    $stmt->bind_result($idParent, $categorie, $parent);
    while ($stmt->fetch())    {
        $idParent;
        $categorie;
        $categorieDrowdown .= '<li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> '.$categorie.'<span class="caret"></span></a>       
            ';      

    $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, category, parent FROM category WHERE parent=?');
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $idParent);
    $stmt->execute();
    $existCount = $stmt->store_result();
        if($existCount == 0){
    echo "nU ai nici o subcategorie lista adaugata";
     exit();
        }
    $stmt->bind_result($idLista, $categorieLista, $parentLista);
    while ($stmt->fetch())    {
        $idLista;
        $categorieLista;
        $categorieDrowdownLista .= ' <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">'.$categorieLista.'</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>      
            ';
        }//close while subcategorie
    }//close while  categorie first select
```

and the display

```
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Admin CMS</a></li>
        <?php echo $categorieDrowdown;//CATEGORIE PRIMA ex: fructe?>    
        <?php echo $categorieDrowdownLista;//CATEGORIE SECUNDA ex:mere?>    

      </ul>
```

Sorry for my english and my problem but I'm newbie

Comment: sorry for double post, but anyone know to help me?please

Comment: You can try to modify the answear I gave in this question, but the simplest is the accepted answear which I edited. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41398248/2630660 The quick and simple way is basically you want to select first with parent 0 then in the while loop make another query which selects parent = category id. I can give you code in a couple of hours I'm on mobile now.

Comment: Thank you, I saw your answer and the explain answer really helped me, because I understood where I did the mistake, thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the first `$stmt` with the second `$stmt` variable, which is why you are getting only the first menu item and the subcategories for this. I have made some adjustments to your code and added an alternative way of doing it, which doesn't have such a performance hit as the loop queries. Also worth mentioning if you don't have a subcatergory you shouldn't exit the script. Simply make an empty placeholder so you can continue with the page loading.

`$stmt->store_result();` doesn't returns the number of rows. You call it to have access to `$stmt->num_rows` property, which will give you the results of found rows. Notice I haven't stored the result in the second example ( [mysqli::store_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php) ), I'm just filling the `$menu` array, without even the need to know if I have results.

```php
$start = microtime( true );
$output = '';

$stmt = $con->prepare( '
    SELECT
        id, category, parent
    FROM category
    WHERE parent = 0
' );
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
// YOU DON'T WANT TO DO THIS... o.O it's fine for debuging tho
//~ if($stmt->num_rows == 0){
    //~ echo "nU ai nici o categorie adaugata";
    //~ exit();
//~ }
// INSTEAD
if( $stmt->num_rows > 0 ){
$stmt->bind_result($idParent, $categorie, $parent);
    while ($stmt->fetch()){
        $output .= '
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                ' . $categorie . ' <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">';

        // rename $stmt to $stmt2 so you'll not overwrite the initial statement
        $stmt2 = $con->prepare('SELECT id, category, parent FROM category WHERE parent=?');
        $stmt2->bind_param('i', $idParent);
        $stmt2->execute();
        $stmt2->store_result();
        // NOR THIS... o.O
        //~ if($stmt2->num_rows == 0){
            //~ echo "nU ai nici o subcategorie lista adaugata";
            //~ exit();
        //~ }
        // INSTEAD
        if( $stmt2->num_rows > 0 ){
            $stmt2->bind_result($idLista, $categorieLista, $parentLista);
            while ($stmt2->fetch()){
                $output .= '
                <li>
                    <a href="#">'.$categorieLista.'</a>
                </li>';
            } //close while subcategorie
        }
        $output .= '
            </ul>
        </li>';
    } // close while  categorie first select
}

echo $output, "\n\n\n";
echo 'Duration: ', microtime( true ) - $start, "\n\n\n";

//-----------------------------------------------------------

// I LIKE IT THIS WAY... ONLY FOR 1 SUBLEVEL THO
// for unlimited dept sub categories you need different approce
$start = microtime( true );
unset( $output );
$output = '';
$menu = array();
$sel = $con->prepare( '
    SELECT
        id, category, parent
    FROM category
    ORDER BY parent, category ASC
' );
$sel->execute();
$sel->bind_result( $id, $category, $parent );
while( $sel->fetch() ){
    if( ! $parent ){ // same as $parent == 0
        $menu[ $id ] = array(
            'name' => $category,
            'sub'  => array(),
        );
    } else {
        $menu[ $parent ]['sub'][ $id ] = array(
            'name' => $category,
        );
    }
}
$sel->close();
foreach( $menu as $id => $item ){
    $output .= '
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            ' . $item['name'] . ' <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">';
    foreach( $item['sub'] as $subid => $subitem ){
        $output .= '
            <li>
                <a href="#">' . $subitem['name'] . '</a>
            </li>';
    }
    $output .= '
        </ul>
    </li>';
}
//~ echo '<pre>', var_dump( $menu ), '</pre>';
echo $output, "\n\n\n";
echo 'Duration: ', microtime( true ) - $start, "\n\n\n";
```

Sample output:

```html
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                fruits <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">apple</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">orange</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">banana</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Pen Pineapple Apple Pen</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                cars <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">moto</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">auto</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                clothes <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">skirt</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>


Duration: 0.0020129680633545



    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            cars <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">auto</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">moto</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            clothes <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">skirt</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            fruits <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">apple</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">banana</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">orange</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Pen Pineapple Apple Pen</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>


Duration: 0.00058293342590332
```

Database structure and data

```sql
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `parent` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `parent` (`parent`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `category` (`id`, `category`, `parent`) VALUES
(1, 'fruits', 0),
(2, 'cars', 0),
(3, 'clothes', 0),
(4, 'moto', 2),
(5, 'auto', 2),
(6, 'apple', 1),
(7, 'orange', 1),
(8, 'banana', 1),
(9, 'skirt', 3),
(10, 'Pen Pineapple Apple Pen', 1);
```

Comment: Thank you, now I see where I mistake, but if use // I LIKE IT THIS WAY... ONLY FOR 1 SUBLEVEL THO
// for unlimited dept sub categories you need different approce that code above, the arrays carts doesnt work, but is WORK fine for only 1 category and 1 subcategory

Comment: What do you mean the arrays carts doesn't work? It should output the same result except in the first example I didn't order the menu.

Comment: Nevermind, i fixed, i told if I used the exemple with ``// for unlimited dept sub categories you need different approce``, was making me problem with others array that I had, but I had only 1 categ and 1 subcateg

Comment: Oh, :). Thats why I gave an SQL example I used to generate the sample output.